# Running casperjs per cronjob on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, phantomjs, casperjs

I have created an application in casperjs which scraps sport data from a website.

I would like to run this application per cronjob on heroku, to save the sports results in a csv, database or external google docs(haven`t decided yet).

However, I have one questions before I start to implement it for heroku:

- I found this [buildpack](https://github.com/leesei/heroku-buildpack-casperjs) for `heroku`, which claims that it can run `casperjs` scirpts. However, do I need `nodejs` to run the script scheduled? Or can I just create a cronjob on heroku?

I really appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most definitely can run your script as a Cron job on heroku.

**Step 1 - Create the app using the buildpack mentioned :**

```
heroku apps:create myapp --stack cedar --buildpack http://github.com/misza222/heroku-buildpack-casperjs.git
```

**Step 2 - Add scheduler and log addons :**

```
heroku addons:add logentries
heroku addons:add scheduler
```

**Step 3 - open the scheduler :**

```
heroku addons:open scheduler
```

or use the dashboard, click My Apps > General Info > Addons > Scheduler

**Step 4 - Setup your cronjob :**

```
./vendor/casperjs/bin/casperjs myCasperScript.js
```

and choose the frequency you want your script to run at.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is it possible to save the output from `casperjs` to a csv on heroku? Is this even allowed? I would appreciate your answer!

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible, heroku's filesystem is read-only. I see 2 solutions, either you write the info to a db (heroku uses postgresql) and you can export easily to csv. Or you upload directly from your script to another server. I'm not sure which one one these would be the simplest knowing that you are not using node.js... Maybe have a look at https://github.com/leesei/heroku-casper-node and see if it can give you ideas

Comment: Thx for your answer! I looked through the link you shared with me, however, this does not solve my problem. One solution I could use could be to create a google sheet where I put my data via json in. Any recommendations if that is possible with casper? I also would appreciate in example in order to accept your answer!

Comment: You should not need an example to your comment in order to accept the answer.  You originally asked if you needed nodejs to run the script or if you can create a cronjob in heroku.  You are now asking another question in the comments.  While @xShirase was kind enough to lead you in the right direction, it seems to me that your new question is best served with a new SO question.  Not intending to be rude, but it seems improper for the question to continue to morph from one thing to another.  You asked a question and he answered it.

Comment: @thtsigma I totally agree with you, these morphing questions happen way too often. mrquad : If you take the time to write a proper question on SO, it sets your brain in 'research' mode. Often times the process of writing down your problem in details will give you the answer. That being said, I'll give you another idea : Casper can POST stuff, so you should be able to send your data to any properly configured endpoint, be it Google sheets or a php script on a server of your choice.